# DataFrame.to_csv() behaves differently when passing compression parameter

Tags: python, pandas

If i use:

```
df.to_csv('dir1/dir2/test.csv.zip')
```

or

```
df.to_csv('dir1/dir2/test.csv', compression='zip')
```

to save a csv file, i found that

1. the path name no matter reletive or absolute will be included in the zip archive
2. the extension name of the actual file in the zip archive will be kept the same with the one you passed in which means if you pass in 'zip' you get a 'zip' in the archive.

None of the above are true if extension name is one of [‘.gz’, ‘.bz2’, or ‘.xz’] or compression mode is one of [‘gzip’, ‘bz2’], are those desirable behavior rather than keep them all the same?

Additionly if you set compression mode with one of ['gzip', 'bz2'] and passin the file name with extension 'csv' you get the compressed archive end with '.csv' which is confusing because you will get all hex code if you open it with a text editor.

Comment: Assuming this behavior is reproducible, it sounds like you should post this in the pandas `issues` tab on their github.

Comment: thanks for your comment i've already posted in the pandas issues